# Merge K sorted arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am given k sorted arrays and need to merge them into one sorted array. We are assuming that n is the total number of elements in all the input arrays and that k=3.

```
public class Merge {

// Create a mergeklists() to merge 3 sorted arrays into one sorted array
// Input: 3 sorted arrays a1[], a2[], a3[]
// Output: one sorted array a[] that contains all the elements from input arrays

public static void merge3lists(int[] a1, int[] a2, int[] a3, int[] a)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int h=0;
    int n = a1.length + a2.length + a3.length;
    for(int k;  a.length < n-1; k++){
        if(a1[i] < a2[j]){
            k = a1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if(a2[j] < a3[h]){
            k = a2[j];
            j++;
        }
        else{
            k = a3[h];
            h++;
        }
    }



}   


public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] l1 = {1,5,9,10,20};

    int[] l2 = {2,4,5,6,7,9,15};

    int[] l3 = {3,8,13,15,22};

    int[] newl = new int[l1.length+l2.length+l3.length];


    merge3lists(l1,l2,l3,newl);
    for(int i = 0; i< newl.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(newl[i]+ " ");
    }


}

}
```

I know that the integers I am using (I,j,and h) are messing up the problem, but I don't think I can use i while comparing all the arrays. I need to use the declared array a, but I'm not sure how to reference it in this case.

Comment: These are arrays, not lists...

Comment: "I know that the integers I am using (I,j,and h) are messing up the problem" - they aren't, you *do* need to keep track of the index for each one of the four arrays

Comment: sorry, i confused the wording. I edited my post

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: okay hmmmmmmmm..

Comment: If the code is not behaving the way you expect, I suggest that you use a debugger to step through it to find the problem.

Comment: The most obvious problem in the merge method is that you're not assigning the elements of `a`. (And that `a` shouldn't be a parameter, but instead a returned value). (And that your loop condition means the loop never executes).

Comment: It looks like you've confused `h` and `k`.  The top of your loop suggests that `k` is an index of iteration; but inside the loop, you're using it to mean "smallest uncopied integer".  I don't think you'd encounter this kind of confusion if you used longer, more meaningful variable names.

Comment: Also, the condition `a.length < n-1` doesn't look right to me - because outside the method, you made the length of `a` to be `n`.  Therefore, the condition is never going to be true, and your code is never going to enter that loop.  (Yes, I know Andy said this already, but I thought I'd spell it out more clearly)

Comment: You have **redeclared** `k`  inside the blocks.  Will that code even compile?

Comment: Thank you it helps when it is put into words I appreciate your help!

Comment: @StephenC I just realized that and fixed it

Comment: I think she is a just a beginner and it happends in beginning , no need for so many question :-) , @Katie can merge two array? If yes then i will give you a tip :-)

Comment: Merge two arrayw and then get their result in an array then again call same method to merge  the merged array with new array , this way you can break the problem in smaller problem and then solve it.

Comment: There's a much more efficient way to do this, using Java's `PriorityQueue<E>`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a preparation exercise to motivate the introduction of array of arrays :)

Number the indices analogous to the lists to avoid confusion.

Identify the list with the smallest element at its current index. Avoid reading beyond the end of the array, as it will result in an exception.

Take this element and proceed.

```
int i1=0;
int i2=0;
int i3=0;
int n = a1.length + a2.length + a3.length;
for( int k = 0;  k < n; k++) {
  int advance = 0;
  int value = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  if (i1 < a1.length && a1[i1] <= value) {
    advance = 1;
    value = a1[i1]; 
  }
  if (i2 < a2.length && a2[i2] <= value) {
    advance = 2;
    value = a2[i2]; 
  }
  if (i3 < a3.length && a3[i3] <= value) {
    advance = 3;
    value = a3[i3]; 
  }
  a[k] = value;
  switch(advance) {
  case 1: i1++; break;
  case 2: i2++; break;
  case 3: i3++; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a ton and now I understand what I am doing wrong. When I run the code it outputs: 1 5 9 10 20 2 4 5 6 7 9 15 3 8 13 15 22 , but I can work to find the problem

Answer (score 4):

To have to method merge an arbitrary number of arrays (`k`), you need to make the method use varargs.

It would also be better to have the method create the result array for you.

You then loop until the result array is filled. For each iteration, you find the smallest of the next value from each source array, and add that to the result array, and step forward in the source array you picked the value from.

Like this:

```
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[]... arrays) {
    // Create result array
    int n = 0;
    for (int[] a : arrays)
        n += a.length;
    int[] result = new int[n];

    // Start at index 0 in each source array
    int[] idx = new int[arrays.length];

    // Merge source arrays into result array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        // Find smallest value
        int minJ = -1, minVal = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++) {
            if (idx[j] < arrays[j].length) {
                int val = arrays[j][idx[j]];
                if (minJ == -1 || val < minVal) {
                    minJ = j;
                    minVal = val;
                }
            }
        }

        // Add to result array and step forward in appropriate source array
        result[i] = minVal;
        idx[minJ]++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Test*

```
int[] merged = mergeArrays(new int[] { 23, 39, 63, 68 },
                           new int[] { 11, 21, 76 },
                           new int[] {  5, 10, 37, 80 },
                           new int[] { 30, 49, 50, 94 },
                           new int[] { 13, 25, 48 });
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

*Output*

```
[5, 10, 11, 13, 21, 23, 25, 30, 37, 39, 48, 49, 50, 63, 68, 76, 80, 94]
```

Comment: The accepted answer isn't bad, but I like this one a lot more. Nice loop

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient algorithm is to use a min-heap.

The algorithm is roughly described as follows:

First, construct a min-heap of size k (in this case size 3 for the three lists) taking the minimum elements in each list.  You would then delete then the minimum element from the heap (noting which list it came from), add it to your newly constructed list, and then insert the next element from that same list which it was initially drawn from.

The time complexity would drop from O(n * k) to O(n * log(k)).  Where n is the total number of elements in the final sorted list.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12853/heap-give-an-on-lg-k-time-algorithm-to-merge-k-sorted-lists-into-one-so