# Sort array of n elements which has k sorted sections

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting, mpi

What is the best way to sort an section-wise sorted array as depicted in the second image?

The problem is performing a quick-sort using [Message Passing Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). The solution is performing quick-sort on array sections obtained by using `MPI_Scatter()` then joining the sorted 
pieces using `MPI_Gather()`.

[image: FLOW]

Problem is that the array as a whole is unsorted but sections of it are.

Merging the sub-sections similarly to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146881/merge-k-sorted-arrays) seems like the best way of sorting the array, but considering that the sub-arrays are already within a single array other sorting algorithms may prove better.

The inputs for a sort function would be the array, it's length and the number of equally sorted sub-sections. 
A signature would look something like `int* sort(int* array, int length, int sections);`

The `sections` parameter can have any value between 1 and 25. The `length` parameter value is greater than 0, a multiple of `sections` and smaller than 2^32.

[image: array]

This is what I am currently using:

```cpp
int* merge(int* input, int length, int sections)
{
    int* sub_sections_indices = new int[sections];
    int* result = new int[length];

    int section_size = length / sections;

    for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++) //initialisation
    {
        sub_sections_indices[i] = 0;
    }
    int min, min_index, current_index;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //merging
    {
        min_index = 0;
        min = INT_MAX;
        for (int j = 0; j < sections; j++)
        {
            if (sub_sections_indices[j] < section_size)
            {
                current_index = j * section_size + sub_sections_indices[j];
                if (input[current_index] < min)
                {
                    min = input[current_index];
                    min_index = j;
                }
            }
        }
        sub_sections_indices[min_index]++;
        result[i] = min;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the typical size of the array? How many sections does it have? Have you tried to implement a couple of algorithms and compare them?

Comment: "Best" in what sense? Easiest to write and maintain / available as a library function?   Something else?

Comment: merge sort without sort?

Comment: I doubt that putting them into a single list provides much opportunity for algorithm improvement.

Comment: Do you need this to be an in place algorithm for some reason?

Comment: @JohnBollinger for CPU and/or memory utilisation. Ease of maintability is not exactly a concern but a good plus.

Comment: @Evg edited the question to answer your inquiries.

Comment: @DragoșCirca, knowing that it is greater than zero/one doesn't really help. You most likely need different algorithms to sort 34 and 34'000 elements.

Comment: Is the number of sections of the same order of magnitude as the number of elements?

Comment: @Evg indeed, this is another problem to consider while formulating a solution. For testing purposes the problem in which this algorithm is needed is ran with inputs ranging from hundreds to hundreds of thousands.

Comment: I've read that [Smoothsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort) takes near O(n) if the input array has sorted sections.

Comment: @DanielJour no, typical cases ranges between 1 and 25

Answer (score -1):

## Optimizing for performance

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228096/5481471) that maintains a min-heap of the smallest item of each sub-array is the best way to handle arbitrary input. However, for small values of `k`, think somewhere between 10 and 100, it might be faster to implement the more naive solutions given in [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146881/merge-k-sorted-arrays); while maintaining the min-heap is only O(log n) for each step, it might have a higher overhead for small values of n than the simple linear scan from the naive solutions.

All these solutions create a copy of the input, and they maintain O(k) state.

## Optimizing for space

The only way to save space I see is to sort in-place. This will be a problem for the algorithms mentioned above. An in-place algorithm will have two swap elements, but any swaps will likely destroy the property that each sub-array is sorted, unless the larger of the swapped pair is re-sorted into the sub-array it is being swapped to, which will result in an O(n²) algorithm. So if you really do need to conserve memory, I think a regular in-place sorting algorithm would have to be used, which defeats your purpose.